# c#- Rollback database before deleting

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I have `Table` `Student`: `ID`, `Name`, `Image`, `PathFileImage`.

There are 2 cases when delete record from `Student`:

- Case 1: when delete record, if delete image file of student by `PathFileImage` successful then done.
- Case 2: when delete record, if delete image file of student by `PathFileImage` failed then rollback database before deleting.

Ex: There are 10 records in `Student`. I delete 3 records.

- In case 1: after deleting, there are 7 records.
- In case 2: after deleting, there are still 10 records.

Could anyone help me to use Transaction to rollback database in case 2?

Thanks all so much for reading!

Comment: Would it be an option to delete the image file **prior** to trying the database delete?

Comment: In my workflow: first delete record in database, then delete file

Comment: Is it an option to do it the other way around?